# Jmeter | Plugins 1.3 - Error while starting Webdrivertest

Tags: selenium-webdriver, jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I just trying to start a webdrivertest at Jmeter with the plugins Extras, Hadoop, ExtraLibs and Webdriver. (all 1.3.0)
When I'm trying to start the script  following error appears:

**Chrome + IE :**

```
jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Test failed! java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.internal.HttpClientFactory.getClientConnectionManager(HttpClientFactory.java:68)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.internal.HttpClientFactory.<init>(HttpClientFactory.java:56)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.internal.HttpClientFactory.<init>(HttpClientFactory.java:60)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.internal.ApacheHttpClient$Factory.getDefaultHttpClientFactory(ApacheHttpClient.java:251)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.internal.ApacheHttpClient$Factory.<init>(ApacheHttpClient.java:228)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.getDefaultClientFactory(HttpCommandExecutor.java:89)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.<init>(HttpCommandExecutor.java:63)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.<init>(HttpCommandExecutor.java:58)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.<init>(DriverCommandExecutor.java:47)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:170)
    at com.googlecode.jmeter.plugins.webdriver.config.ChromeDriverConfig.createBrowser(ChromeDriverConfig.java:61)
    at com.googlecode.jmeter.plugins.webdriver.config.ChromeDriverConfig.createBrowser(ChromeDriverConfig.java:21)
    at com.googlecode.jmeter.plugins.webdriver.config.WebDriverConfig.getPreparedBrowser(WebDriverConfig.java:233)
    at com.googlecode.jmeter.plugins.webdriver.config.WebDriverConfig.threadStarted(WebDriverConfig.java:220)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread$ThreadListenerTraverser.addNode(JMeterThread.java:610)
    at org.apache.jorphan.collections.HashTree.traverseInto(HashTree.java:998)
    at org.apache.jorphan.collections.HashTree.traverse(HashTree.java:980)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.threadStarted(JMeterThread.java:579)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.initRun(JMeterThread.java:567)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:257)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)




jmeter.JMeter: Uncaught exception:  java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/openqa/selenium/os/Kernel32
    at org.openqa.selenium.os.ProcessUtils.killWinProcess(ProcessUtils.java:133)
    at org.openqa.selenium.os.ProcessUtils.killProcess(ProcessUtils.java:81)
    at org.openqa.selenium.os.UnixProcess$SeleniumWatchDog.destroyHarder(UnixProcess.java:248)
    at org.openqa.selenium.os.UnixProcess$SeleniumWatchDog.access$200(UnixProcess.java:200)
    at org.openqa.selenium.os.UnixProcess.destroy(UnixProcess.java:124)
    at org.openqa.selenium.os.CommandLine.destroy(CommandLine.java:153)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.stop(DriverService.java:190)
    at com.googlecode.jmeter.plugins.webdriver.config.ChromeDriverConfig.quitBrowser(ChromeDriverConfig.java:69)
    at com.googlecode.jmeter.plugins.webdriver.config.ChromeDriverConfig.quitBrowser(ChromeDriverConfig.java:21)
    at com.googlecode.jmeter.plugins.webdriver.config.WebDriverConfig.threadFinished(WebDriverConfig.java:244)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread$ThreadListenerTraverser.addNode(JMeterThread.java:612)
    at org.apache.jorphan.collections.HashTree.traverseInto(HashTree.java:998)
    at org.apache.jorphan.collections.HashTree.traverse(HashTree.java:980)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.threadFinished(JMeterThread.java:584)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:315)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

**Firefox :**

```
jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Test failed! java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.internal.HttpClientFactory.getClientConnectionManager(HttpClientFactory.java:68)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.internal.HttpClientFactory.<init>(HttpClientFactory.java:56)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.internal.HttpClientFactory.<init>(HttpClientFactory.java:60)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.internal.ApacheHttpClient$Factory.getDefaultHttpClientFactory(ApacheHttpClient.java:251)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.internal.ApacheHttpClient$Factory.<init>(ApacheHttpClient.java:228)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.getDefaultClientFactory(HttpCommandExecutor.java:89)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.<init>(HttpCommandExecutor.java:63)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.<init>(HttpCommandExecutor.java:58)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.internal.NewProfileExtensionConnection.start(NewProfileExtensionConnection.java:95)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.startClient(FirefoxDriver.java:275)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:116)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:220)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:215)
    at com.googlecode.jmeter.plugins.webdriver.config.FirefoxDriverConfig.createBrowser(FirefoxDriverConfig.java:95)
    at com.googlecode.jmeter.plugins.webdriver.config.FirefoxDriverConfig.createBrowser(FirefoxDriverConfig.java:21)
    at com.googlecode.jmeter.plugins.webdriver.config.WebDriverConfig.getPreparedBrowser(WebDriverConfig.java:233)
    at com.googlecode.jmeter.plugins.webdriver.config.WebDriverConfig.threadStarted(WebDriverConfig.java:220)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread$ThreadListenerTraverser.addNode(JMeterThread.java:610)
    at org.apache.jorphan.collections.HashTree.traverseInto(HashTree.java:998)
    at org.apache.jorphan.collections.HashTree.traverse(HashTree.java:980)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.threadStarted(JMeterThread.java:579)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.initRun(JMeterThread.java:567)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:257)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

**Apache JMeter Version 2.13

Java    1.8.0.45**

I also used Jmeter 2.13 with the same plugins (1.2.1) and it works perfectly. But for testing I need the 1.3 plugins.

Does anybody use Jmeter with plugins 1.3 and got the same error?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You have an issue in  **the fact that you have different versions of same JAR in lib :**

- httpclient-4.2.6.jar
- httpclient-4.5.jar
- httpcore-4.2.5.jar
- httpcore-4.4.1.jar
- httpmime-4.2.6.jar
- httpmime-4.5.jar

You need to keep the most up to date version of each not both.

See a full tutorial on this at:

- http://www.ubik-ingenierie.com/blog/leverage-your-load-testing-using-jmeter-and-selenium-webdriver/

Comment: Thanks for your fast answer!

I have tried it again as you said, but there is the same error. I expand all jars and start with Standard, then Extras, Extralibs and Finally webdriver. I got Jmeter 2.13 from http://jmeter.apache.org/download_jmeter.cgi (the zip-one) and Plugins from http://jmeter-plugins.org/downloads/all/. Is there a possiblility to send you the structure of folders and content privat? Cause thats over 2000 lines and I think that would be to much text here :D

Comment: For me this maven repository was missing: http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpclient/4.5.2

Answer (score 0):

> jmeter.JMeter:
>
> Uncaught exception:  java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
> org/openqa/selenium/os/Kernel32

To fix the above error, download JNA jar it with its dependency here:

http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/j/Downloadjna330platformjar.htm
http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/j/Downloadjna330jar.htm

And put it in lib folder.